# Music lags after pause

Tags: iphone, music, ios

I'm listening to music on my iPhone. For some reason I need to pause it, so I press the button on my iPhone earbud thingies. Then when I start the music up again, it very often lags like crazy. The music played fine before, but after I resume, it's just impossible to listen to. Take up my phone and turn on the screen and lagging often goes away. Turn the screen off again and lagging sometimes comes back. Sometimes not.

Anyone else experienced this? Any idea what's going on? Could understand it if there was some rough process hogging resources in the back, but I mean, it plays fine until I press pause and I don't touch anything else until I resume it.

It happens with both the Music app and the Spotify app.